# how to take an edit text text in val from view model

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I have this code in my view model

```
 class SearchViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(jobUseCase: JobUseCase) : ViewModel() {
    val job = jobUseCase.getSearchJob(...).asLiveData()
}
```

but the`getSearchJob()` need the parameter to fill. and this where I use the job in the activity

```
private fun getSearchData() {
    searchViewModel.job.observe(this, { job ->
        if (job != null) {
            when (job) {
                is Resource.Loading -> binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    jobAdapter.setData(job.data)
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

but I don't know how to fill the `getSearchJob()` parameter in the val. or if there is any idea please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler for you to have a simple MutableLiveData instance, from which you can expose a regular liveData that can be exposed to the activity, and a onTextChanged Listener simply updates the viewModel, jobUseCase.getSearchJob(...) gets the data, and then you can set the new value to MutableLiveData instance.

if you need something more elegant, then let jobUseCase.getSearchJob(...) take in a flow instance that you can pass in data to which in turn fires off your job livedata

Simple Mutable livedata based example

```
class SearchViewModel1 constructor(private val jobUseCase: JobUseCase) : ViewModel() {

    private val _internalMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val publicLiveData: LiveData<String> = _internalMutableLiveData


    fun updateSearchTerm(term: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = jobUseCase.getSearchJob(term)
            _internalMutableLiveData.value = result
        }
    }

}

class JobUseCase {
    suspend fun getSearchJob(term: String): String {
        // fetch Data here
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have some example?

Comment: Are you looking for a flow example or simple Mutable Livedata, I can update my answer

Comment: I updated my answer with the simple mutable live data example